# jquery focusout function inside the division or table

Tags: jquery

I have a function that will display the division having a table inside on it. On the thead area there will be an input type and a label. The label will show first, if you click the label it will hide and the input type will show. it works fine, if you click outside of the division. But it works nothing if you click inside the division or table. Here's my function.

```
$('.add-header').on('click',function(){
    var header = $(this).parent().find('#header-name').val();
    $('tbody.content').prepend('<div class="groupborder" style="border-color:#333333"><tr> \
        <td> \
            <table class="tables_details" style="width:100%;"> \
                <th id="groups" data-id="'+headcount+'" style="background-color: #333333; width: 100%;" > \
                    <label style="display:inline-block;float:left; margin-left:900px; width:60px; font-weight: bold; color:#FFFFFF;">\
                        Sub-total:\
                    </label> \
                    <label class="head" style="margin-bottom:-4px;width:300px;height:20px;border:1px solid red;display: block; margin-left: -930px; float: left; font-size: 11px;; color:#FFFFFF;">\
                        HEADER '+headcount+'\
                    </label> \
                    <input type="text" name="header_name[]" class="edit-input" style="width:300px;height:20px; display: none; margin-left: -930px; float: left; padding-left:5px;" value="HEADER '+headcount+'"/> \
                    <input class="header_id" name="header_id[]" type="hidden" value="'+headcount+'"> \
                    <a href="" class="rm-header fa fa-times-circle fa-lg" style="float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:5px"></a> \
                    <label style="display:inline-block; float:right; margin-right:30px; font-weight: bold; color:#FFFFFF;" class="total" id="total_'+headcount+'" data-sub_id="'+headcount+'">0.00</label></th> \
                    <input name="header_subtotal[]" class="stotal" id="stotal_'+headcount+'" type="hidden" value="0.00"> </th> \
                <tbody class="subcontent tbody"></tbody> \
            </table>\
      </td> </tr></div>');
    // header tweak 
    var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
    edit(dad);

    $('.head').on('click', function(){
        var dad = $(this).parent().parent();
        edit(dad);
    })
    sort();
    headcount+=1;
    $('.rm-header').on('click',function(){
        a = $(this);
        headrm(a);
        return false;
    })
})

function edit(dad){
    dad.find('.head:first').hide();
    dad.find('.edit-input:first').show().focus().select();

    $('.edit-input').focusout(function(){
        var dad = $(this).parent();
        var x = $(this).parent().find('.edit-input').val();
        $(this).hide();
        dad.find('.head').text(x).show();           
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you also show the HTML Code?

Comment: the html code is inside the ('.add-header').on('click',function(){}) using prepend

Comment: the HTML that you are appending that to would be helpful. My first guess is that you have conflicting events, but since you are navigating with parent(), we can't see what events might be applied where.

Comment: You can't prepend `<div>` to `<tbody>`. The children of `<tbody>` have to be `<tr>`.